# Are these glitches?

Tags: bug, reputation

A few days ago I modified some Tag Wikis, and they still haven't shown up on my "Research Assistant" tab. I know there's sometimes a delay, but it's been a few days.

More importantly, I somehow got 100 rep on all the forums because of trust, but I also got that on the Raspberry Pi community, making me go from 200 rep to 300 rep.

I also don't know if these go in Meta, or if they go anywhere, so let me know if this should be deleted.

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: I believe I rejected at least one of your tag edits.

Comment: I've gotten reputation from at least 7. I got +2 for each

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: They're not showing up in my badge, and I'm wondering if the other reputation thing is normal.

Comment: Join me on Raspberry PI chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have screwed one up for you.  I approved the edit and "improved" on it, but then I also switched two synonym tags:

[raspicam](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspicam) <-> [camera-board](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera-board)

Previously, the former was a synonym for the latter, which means the tag that actually got used was camera-board.  I created that mapping a while ago, but I'm pretty sure I did the reverse of what I intended because raspicam seems like the more appropriate tag to me.

I noticed this when your edit came up and corrected the mapping.  I'd think approving the edit would still count, but maybe because I either chose "improve" or then switched it (which also switches the tag wiki details, since synonyms don't have any; note that my edit of your edit was substantial and the wiki now reads "The CSI interface camera from the Raspberry Pi Foundation, available in a NoIR night version."), it could be the points you should have gotten were eaten by the system.  I can't find a way to tell the difference.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!